# executing a command as an administrator in a single line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, admin

is there a single line command wherein I can run a command as an administrator from any non-admin account to create a new user using the administrator username and password?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `sudo`.

Comment: i used the following command : runas /profile /user:administrator "cmd /c net user /add [username] [password]" and it works but it prompts for a password in the next line. what I want is to merge the password in the above command. Is that possible??

Comment: @vjlxmi You didn't specify that you were talking about Windows in the original question. `sudo` is a Unix command, I don't know the answer for Windows. I've updated the tags on your question to indicate this. However, this isn't really a programming question, so I don't think it's appropriate for this site; instead, it belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: yeah sorry forgot to mention that. and Thanks for your response.